# Joining two of the same id to the same table under different names?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have an odd thing I'm trying to do for a rest API.  I have a `Order` table, and it's laid out like this:

```
ID | Billing Address | Shipping Address | Status
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 1               | 1                | 1
2  | 1               | 1                | 1
```

and I want to join a `customers` table to it.  Now, I would like to join the customers for both the billing and shipping address, like almost sort of have two distinct customers returned within the result set. Can I get a nested result of join?

`customers` table is something like

```
ID | First name      | Last Name        | Street Address
--------------------------------------------------------
1  | Bob             | Bobber           | 2 Winding Way
2  | 1               | 1                | 1
```

I'm a pretty big newbie with this and I can't even get it to combine two of the results in there messy, let alone try to actually clarify which is which.

I'm trying something like

```
select * from "order" 
 inner join 
"customers as shipping" 
   on "order"."shipping_address" = "shipping"."customer_id" 
 inner join 
"order_status" 
   on "order"."order_status_id" = "order_status"."order_status_id" 
 inner join 
"customers as billing" 
   on "order"."billing_address" = "billing"."customer_id"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to join the table `customers` under two different aliases.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
order o 
INNER JOIN customers b ON o.billing_address = b.id
INNER JOIN customers s ON o.shipping_address = s.id;
```

You can join same table several times, when you use different alias (b and s in this example).

Also, there is no need to quote the table names and column names as Postgres is case insensitive by default (unless you used quotes to create tables and define rows too, for some odd reason).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM order o
     INNER JOIN customers b on o.billing_address = b.id
     INNER JOIN customers s on o.shipping_address = s.id returns `

Comment: I have a question then... When I run this query, it seems to return 2 of each field in the customer table (I suppose this is the expected behavior after all).  It's tripping up my API. Do you know of a specific way to alias the result or should I ask this in my specific language / framework as it's not a db thing?

Comment: It's caused by * of course. Now you have to select your specific columns, eg. `SELECT s.columnname, b.columnname` - not sure what the column names are. If they really are what you showed in the input and have spaces in them, you will have to use eg., `"s.First Name"`

Comment: I think you've shown me the holy grail I've been looking for for a while now.  My query is `select o, s.name shipping, b.name billing from ... ` as we had earlier and it seems to return column delimited ones.  I think my mistake was messing in a query builder before.  Thank you so much!!!